# I am facing issue in executing our Selenium test on safari browser on Mac machine

Tags: macos, selenium, safaridriver

We are facing issue in switching to the new window on safari browser. Below is our code used for switching the window.

```
public void switchToWindow() {
        Set<String> availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String strWinHandle : availableWindows) {
            driver.switchTo().window(strWinHandle);
        }
    }
```

In availableWindows, it returns all window handles but instead of switching to new window, it is switching to parent window. 
Above code works fine on all other browsers.

Selenium version - 3.11.0
Safari version - 11.1.1

Comment: you can use CurrentHandle http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/

Comment: But how to get CurrentHandle?

Comment: you can use getWindowHandle method of driver to get current window handle.

Comment: getWindowHandle  will return window handle of parent window. we are facing issue in switch to new window

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
public void switchToWindow() {
       String curWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> availableWindows = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String strWinHandle : availableWindows) {
            if(!curWinHandle.equals(strWinHandle))
               driver.switchTo().window(strWinHandle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: we tried with above code also, It will work fine while switching to new window but if fails when we have to close the last opened window.It will close parent window then.

Comment: how do you close the last opened window only?

Comment: switching to last window using above method and then driver.close()

Comment: driver.close() closes all windows. there is no option to close only one window. may be you can try shortcut keys to close the current window. But I am not sure about it.